# Presenting the index labels in the x axis of a Scatter Plot with Seaborn

Tags: python, label, seaborn

I have created a Scatter Plot with Seaborn and I was thinking that if I could present the index labels of the Observations on the x axis --rotated by 90 degrees-- this would help the reader interpret the plot.  However I do not know how to do this.

My data:

```
                      Response8  Nulls_prevalence
Employment_Info_1     0.001348              0.00
Employment_Info_4    -0.000049              0.11
Medical_History_1     0.078445              0.15
Employment_Info_6     0.003095              0.18
Family_Hist_4        -0.119424              0.32
Insurance_History_5  -0.003648              0.43
Family_Hist_2        -0.004765              0.48
Family_Hist_3        -0.003509              0.58
Family_Hist_5        -0.003889              0.70
Medical_History_15    0.263364              0.75
Medical_History_24    0.112906              0.94
Medical_History_32    0.485493              0.98
Medical_History_10    0.203842              0.99
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.regplot(x = 'Nulls_prevalence', y='Response8' , data = plot_data8, fit_reg=False)

plt.title('Response8:  Nulls_prevalence of Predictors vs. Correlation with Target')

plt.xlabel('Nulls Prevalence of Predictor')

plt.ylabel('Correlation of Predictor with Target')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]

I gave it a shot but I could not make all the index labels appear (only a subset appeared on the x axis).

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are asking is the functionality of the seaborn's rugplot function.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.regplot(x = 'Nulls_prevalence', y='Response8' , data = plot_data8, fit_reg=False)

sns.rugplot(plot_data8['Nulls_prevalence'], ax=ax) # Don't forget to pass the axis from regplot

plt.title('Response8:  Nulls_prevalence of Predictors vs. Correlation with Target')

plt.xlabel('Nulls Prevalence of Predictor')

plt.ylabel('Correlation of Predictor with Target')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need, `plt.xticks`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8)
sns.regplot(x = 'Nulls_prevalence', y='Response8' , data = plot_data8, fit_reg=False)

plt.title('Response8:  Nulls_prevalence of Predictors vs. Correlation with Target')

plt.xlabel('Nulls Prevalence of Predictor')

plt.ylabel('Correlation of Predictor with Target')

plt.tight_layout()

#plt.xticks line
plt.xticks(plot_data8['Nulls_prevalence'], rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @user8270077 Did this help you?